# SQL difference between Multiple Rows having the same ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, inner-join, aggregate-functions

SQL Sever 2012

Raw Data

```
ID   VAL   Time
+---+----+---------------------+
| 2 |  1 | 2015-05-09 12:54:39 |
| 3 | 10 | 2015-05-09 12:54:39 |
| 2 |  1 | 2015-05-09 12:56:39 |
| 3 | 10 | 2015-05-09 12:56:39 |
| 2 |  5 | 2015-05-09 13:48:30 |
| 3 | 16 | 2015-05-09 13:48:30 |
| 2 |  7 | 2015-05-09 15:01:09 |
| 3 | 20 | 2015-05-09 15:01:09 |
+---+----+---------------------+
```

I have a table where VAL is increasing forever in time. I want to manipulate the data to show how much VAL is increasing for each ID over time. So Val at Time2 - Val at Time1

Ideal Result:

```
ID   VALI   Time
+---+----+---------------------+
| 2 |  0 | 2015-05-09 12:56:39 |
| 3 |  0 | 2015-05-09 12:56:39 |
| 2 |  4 | 2015-05-09 13:48:30 |
| 3 |  6 | 2015-05-09 13:48:30 |
| 2 |  2 | 2015-05-09 15:01:09 |
| 3 |  4 | 2015-05-09 15:01:09 |
+---+----+---------------------+
```

Code so far:

```
select
t1.Time,t1.[ID],t2.[VAL]-t1.[VAL] AS [ValI]
from #tempTable t1
inner join #tempTable t2 ON t1.[ID]=t2.[ID]
AND t1.[Time]<t2.[Time]
```

I need to calculate the difference between the current timestamp and ONLY the Time right before current timestamp not all timestamps before the current timestamp. As of now I get a lot of repeating values when VAL did not change.

Comment: Look at the LAG() function for Sql Server.

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sql query for difference between current row and previous row based on datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46972621/sql-query-for-difference-between-current-row-and-previous-row-based-on-datetime)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this.

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE (ID INT,   VAL INT,  [Time] DATETIME)
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES
(2,  1 ,'2015-05-09 12:54:39'),
(3, 10 ,'2015-05-09 12:54:39'),
(2,  1 ,'2015-05-09 12:56:39'),
(3, 10 ,'2015-05-09 12:56:39'),
(2,  5 ,'2015-05-09 13:48:30'),
(3, 16 ,'2015-05-09 13:48:30'),
(2,  7 ,'2015-05-09 15:01:09'),
(3, 20 ,'2015-05-09 15:01:09')


;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY [Time]) RN FROM @MyTable
)
SELECT T1.ID, T2.VAL - T1.VAL AS VALI, T2.Time FROM CTE T1
    INNER JOIN CTE T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID AND T1.RN = T2.RN - 1
ORDER BY T1.[Time], T1.ID
```

Result:

```
ID          VALI        Time
----------- ----------- -----------------------
2           0           2015-05-09 12:56:39.000
3           0           2015-05-09 12:56:39.000
2           4           2015-05-09 13:48:30.000
3           6           2015-05-09 13:48:30.000
2           2           2015-05-09 15:01:09.000
3           4           2015-05-09 15:01:09.000
```

Comment: Looks like it works. Is there a way to insert the CTE into a temp table I need to do some additional filtering?

Comment: You can write `insert into` before select. like `WITH CTE AS ( ... ) INSERT INTO TempTable
SELECT ... `

Comment: @user3055889 What additional filtering? Inserting into a temp table is kinda defeating one of the main benefits of a CTE? You should be able to filter your CTE as needed without having to dump it into a temp table.

Comment: @Shawn thanks for the idea just added a where statement to the CTE and was able to do the work there.

Comment: Also, FYI: this would definitely be the preferred way to do this in SQL < 2012, but using the window functions (`LEAD/LAG`) in 2012+ results in a flat execution plan that will perform a good bit faster.

Answer (score 0):

You could first put a Rank on your #tempTable ordered by Time descending, and partitioned by ID.

Then your join becomes this:

```
select
    t1.Time,
    t1.[ID],
    t1.[VAL] - t2.[VAL] AS [ValI]
from #tempTable t1
inner join #tempTable t2 ON t1.[ID] = t2.[ID]
    AND t2.Rank = (t1.Rank + 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here this should work:

```
 select id, time, val-prevval val1 from (
 select * , lag(val, 1, 0) over(partition by  id order by val, time) prevVal from #Temp)A
 order by time
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have `LAG`

**[DEMO](http://rextester.com/FGKB7753)**

```
   SELECT
        id
      , val - LAG(val, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY time ASC) AS VALI
      , time
    FROM #TempTable
    ORDER BY time ASC, ID ASC
```

Comment: Tried this but I get 0 for all of my differences along with some null values.

Comment: @user3055889 Works for me with your example data. See this demo http://rextester.com/FGKB7753

Answer (score 0):

`LAG()` became available in SQL 2012. This allows you to take the current row's `val` and subtract the `val` from the previous row, grouped by the `id` and sorted by `Time`. That will return `NULL` for the first two rows, since they don't have a previous record to compare to. You can exclude them by placing the query in a sub-select then applying a `WHERE valDiff IS NULL`, or you can default the `valDiff` using the third argument of `LAG()` > `LAG(Val,1,0)` to default the first two rows to `0`.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d9648/1)

**MS SQL Server 2017 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 ( ID int, VAL int, [Time] datetime) ;

INSERT INTO t1 ( ID, Val, [Time] )
VALUES 
    ( 2, 1 , '2015-05-09 12:54:39')
  , ( 3, 10, '2015-05-09 12:54:39')
  , ( 2, 1 , '2015-05-09 12:56:39')
  , ( 3, 10, '2015-05-09 12:56:39')
  , ( 2, 5 , '2015-05-09 13:48:30')
  , ( 3, 16, '2015-05-09 13:48:30')
  , ( 2, 7 , '2015-05-09 15:01:09')
  , ( 3, 20, '2015-05-09 15:01:09')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT s1.ID
  , s1.ValDiff
  , FORMAT(s1.[Time], 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss') AS fTime
FROM (
  SELECT ID
    , Val - LAG(Val,1) OVER ( PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY [Time],ID ) AS ValDiff
    , [Time]
  FROM t1
) s1
WHERE s1.valDiff IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY s1.[Time],s1.ID
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d9648/1/0)**:

```
| ID |    ValI |               fTime |
|----|---------|---------------------|
|  2 |       0 | 2015-05-09 12:56:39 |
|  3 |       0 | 2015-05-09 12:56:39 |
|  2 |       4 | 2015-05-09 01:48:30 |
|  3 |       6 | 2015-05-09 01:48:30 |
|  2 |       2 | 2015-05-09 03:01:09 |
|  3 |       4 | 2015-05-09 03:01:09 |
```